# What image (with smaller or higher DPI) is used to prepare the image when appropriate is missing?

Tags: android, image, android-resources, dpi, screen-density

I have phone with xhdpi screen. I use image abc.jpg but there is no such image for xhdpi. But there is an image with higher DPI (drawable-xxhdpi/abc.jpg) and with lower (drawable-hdpi/abc.jpg). **Which one will be used to prepare (scale) the image for my density screen?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpts from Android developers page:

> Note: Using a density qualifier doesn't imply that the resources are
>   only for screens of that density. **If you don't provide alternative
>   resources with qualifiers that better match the current device
>   configuration, the system may use whichever resources are the *best
>   match*.**

**Best Match**:

> If the qualifier in question is screen pixel density, Android selects
>   the option that most closely matches the device screen density. In
>   general, **Android prefers scaling down a larger original image to
>   scaling up a smaller original image.**

*Source page : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch*

Based on this I'd assume that the higher dpi image will be used, however a visual check would probably confirm this i.e. if the image isn't blurry it is probably safe to assume it hasn't been upscaled.